# "-[_NSXPCDistantObject ___nsx_pingHost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000408140" error while working with photo editing extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Started working on a photo editing extension in Xcode. no matter what I do whenever I select my extension to edit a photo the app crashes with the following error.

The following is the screenshot of the error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnAgw.png

After finding the solution for hours only thing I got was to uninstall and restart the app, but that too didn’t work.

For more understanding, I have attached a Google Drive video link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dwDCuRqMMgV-gWYVZPOtt5IgWBhaqAFR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The thing is I haven’t written any code as such. I created a project. then went to file>new>target> photo editing extension, created a new extension. Then I activated the scheme and ran the app with photos. Ideally, it should launch the editing and blank black screen but in my case, it crashes after showing a loader.

Comment: @burnsi I have attached a video link to be more understandable.

Comment: Also, the site I have been referring to is: 

https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iOS_8_Photo_Editing_Extension

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. Do you have M1 mac?

Comment: Yes I am using M1 mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO I found the solution to this. Firstly, I was opening Xcode using Rosetta. Once I unchecked it. I was able to run the extension. So this can be a bridging problem between intel to apple silicon. If anyone has any idea about the same in-depth please comment below.